# Issue with evaporation rate of water

Tags: thermodynamics, water, vapor-pressure

> The **evaporation rate** of water (kg/s) is given by:
>
> $$g = \frac{P}{P_o} AΘ$$
>
> Where $P$ is given in Pascals and $A$ is the surface area (in $m^2$) and $Θ$ is the empirical evaporation coefficient:
>
> $$Θ = 12v + 16$$
>
> where $v$ the wind speed (perpendicular to the water's surface).
>
> a) Calculate the evaporated mass of water in one hour when $v = 0$.
>
> b) Calculate the enthalpy and entropy difference within $1$ hour when $v = 0$.

What I have tried:

a) I understand $P$ to be the partial pressure of water vapor in moist air and $P_o$ to be the atmospheric pressure of moist air.

I am not given neither the values for these pressures nor the surface area... How am I supposed to calculate the evaporated mass without such data? (It's stated that all the necessary information is provided)

b)

$$\Delta H = \Delta U + P\Delta V$$

Holding fixed the number of molecules:

$$dH = TdS+ VdP$$

But again I don't have enough information...

Are there flaws in this exercise or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct, you cannot calculate the answer in absolute terms, e.g. kg, so you must answer the question in terms of the pressures, areas and the constant 16 (since *v* drops out). How does theta become gamma, though? Typo??

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. I'll fix it.

Comment: What kind of exercise are they assigning! Basically this asks for "how many second are in one hour" in a convoluted way.

Comment: Yeah, this exercise is not really useful. I am interested in doing exercises in vapor-gas equilibrium (saturated vapor), which is described by the Clausius–Clapeyron relation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporation#Factors_influencing_the_rate_of_evaporation

Comment: So if anyone has a set of exercises on it, could you please share it? I have more exercises on it but are confusing like above.